# Custom metric Turns to NaN after many steps in each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, precision-recall

I am using custom Recall and Precision metrics in my model. I know they have them built into Keras but I only care about one of the classes.

As I begin an epoch, I get values printing out for the metrics but after many steps one metrics returns NaN and a few hundred epochs later the second custom metric shows NaN.

The recall metric is written in the same

```
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Calculates precision metric over gun label
    Precision = TP/(TP+FP)
    '''
    #I only care about the last label
    y_true = y_true[:,-1]
    y_pred = y_pred[:,-1]
    y_pred = tf.where(y_pred>.5, 1, 0)

    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)

    true_positives = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    false_positive = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.logical_and(tf.not_equal(y_true,y_pred), y_pred==1), 1, 0))
    false_positive = tf.cast(false_positive, tf.float32)
    precision = true_positives / (true_positives + false_positive)
    return precision
```

Training a multi label so my last dense layer is `preds = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid', name='Classifier')(x)`.

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy', precision, recall])
model.fit(train_ds, steps_per_epoch=10000, validation_data=valid_ds, validation_steps=1181,  epochs=200)
```

```
18/10000 [............] - ETA: 6:43 - loss: 0.6919 - accuracy: 0.0046 - precision: 0.2597 - recall: 0.4691

315/10000 [...........] - ETA: 7:56 - loss: 0.4174 - accuracy: 0.1145 - precision: nan - recall: 0.6115

10000/10000 [=========>] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0797 - accuracy: 0.5432 - precision: nan - recall: nan
10000/10000 [=========>] - 576s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0797 - accuracy: 0.5432 - precision: nan - recall: nan - val_loss: 0.0557 - val_accuracy: 0.5807 - val_precision: 0.9698 - val_recall: 0.9529
```

At the beginning of each epoch, the metrics show numbers again but after many steps they go back to NaN. With observation, I can confirm they do not go to 0 nor 1 right before NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a divide by zero. I added a small value in each denominator which solves the problem. This occurs if there are no positive predictions by the network in any batch. This is why it occurred intermittently.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

precision = true_positives / (true_positives + false_positive + K.epsilon())
```